# changing text color in label in C# with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to change the color of a text in a label per condition.

I have tried the following option but none of them works:

```
if (gameNameTXT.Text != "")
{
    pubName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    pubName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(11, 102, 35);
    pubName.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "green");
}
```

(`pubName` in the ID of the label)

I have located the snipped code in the `Page_Load` section and/or the `Page_Init` section.

What I want is that the color of the text changes to green if the user wrote something in the text box.

Comment: The short answer is you should do this with javascript. The longer answer will be more complicated - but will ultimately end with "you should do this with javascript".

Comment: I hope your code is immersed in an event handler such as public void GameNameTextBox_OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs ev) {...}. Also that your Textbox has an AutoPostback = "true"

Answer (score 0):

do you try on onChange event of gameNameTXT?
may be you need set AutoPostBack=true